# Is there anyway to save javascript breakpoints in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, breakpoints

I just spent about an hour setting breakpoints in a few javascript files. Most likely I'll need to use these same breakpoints for a few days now and in between I'm required to power down my workstation.

Is there anyway that I can save this set of breakpoints somehow and in the morning just re-open them and have them all automagically reset?

Thanks,

Comment: Firebug allows breakpoints

Comment: But can it save those breakpoints somewhere so that between restarts I don't need to reset them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place "debugger;" in the place where you want breakpoints.
After you are done programming, remove any "debugger;" so it doesn't go in production.

Edit:
"debugger;" is a keyword that triggers a breakpoint in the browser's JS machine.

Comment: Yeah that's a usable workaround. There isn't just a "save/load breakpoints to/from file" button somewhere that I could use?

Comment: Ah, I just found out that "debugger" is actually a keyword that will trigger the debugger. Cool, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I see in the way i've written the answer, it's not very clear that debugger; should be written in the code, where one would want the JS machine to stop execution.

Comment: Yeah I thought you were just suggesting I leave an eye-catcher in the code that I can ctrl-F each time to reset the breakpoints. maybe you could update your answer for future searchers?